# i cannot login to the page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-login

iam trying to create a login page for  users whom i have created using django admin can login. But by the below code i cannot login i.e after clicking login button im not being redirected to the page i have given.

forms1.py

```
    from django import forms

    class UserForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 
    'Username'}))
        password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs= 
   {'placeholder': 'Password'}))
        fields = ['username', 'password']
```

views.py

```
    def Userform(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                userObj = form.cleaned_data
                username = userObj['username']
                password = userObj['password']
                user = authenticate(Username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/')
        else:
            form = UserForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form' : form})
```

urls

```
    urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('user/',user),
    path('login/',Userform),
    ]
```

index.html

```
     <form class="login-form" method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                 <button type="submit">login</button>                 
     </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be some problems with your code

`forms1.py`

> First of all fields should be a part of Meta class. Secondly, you actually don't require fields because you are manually taking the fields

`views.py`

> user = authenticate(Username=username, password=password)

The Username should be lowercase `username`. But this is probably just a typo here.

Finally you don't actually need to make your view for login. There are inbuilt functions available in authviews

[Auth Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create UserForm as there are built in functions that will handle login, logout and passwords using django.contrib.auth.

Have a good read of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/

Maybe something along the lines of:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
         user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
         if user is not None:
             auth_login(request, user)
             return redirect('user')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth.views

path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login')
```

using auth.views.login  will try to render the login.html by default. So rename index.html to login.html

login.html

```
<form method="POST">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: im getting an error "cannot find reference to 'login' in views.py " in the above defined path. i have changed the view as above and renamed the html page and changed the path as above

Comment: @user8543557 Have a look at this tutorial. I am still quite new to Django but together with the Django docs it helped me understand how the user authentication system worked. https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-login-and-logout/